# VSCode Asp.Net core command line arguments when debugging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Just been reading [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2016/09/20/database-migrations-and-seeding-in-asp-net-core.aspx) article from Scott Allen.

The approach to specify command line arguments to .net core seems intersing, but how do we pass those arguments from VS Code when running with debugger (Normally using F5 command if launch.json is setup)?

e.g `dotnet run dropdb migratedb seeddb`

Comment: Have you tried adding `"args": ["dropdb", "migratedb", "seeddb"]` to your `launch.json` configuration?

Comment: @MattBierner Thanks, that was simple and works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear. I've posted the comment as an answer so that you can close this question out

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Copying over answer from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189755/vscode-asp-net-core-command-line-arguments-when-debugging#comment69586868_41189755)*

---

**Note**: `launch.json` is found in the `.vscode` folder under your project.

In your `launch.json`, try adding:

```
"args": ["dropdb", "migratedb", "seeddb"]
```

to the target [launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations).

**Providing Context Inside launch.json**

Your `launch.json` will contain an empty `args` element by default which looks something like:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<YourProjName>/bin/Debug/net6.0/YourProjName.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/<YourProjName>",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
            .
            .
            .
            // launch.json file continues...
```

Comment: When I write `"type": "dotnet"`, linter said `Property args is not allowed.` at line `"args": []`.  So I just want to warn for everyone that to use `args` the `type` must be `coreclr`.